# When do you use encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder: on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, initwithcoder

As my question in the subject above states, what requirements do you typically have to meet in order to say "Ok, I need `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` instantiation for this"? Typically you can write object state to `NSUserDefaults`, so I'm curious when do you experts decide to use one vs the other?

Answer (score 10):

`initWithCoder:` is used by the OS when un-archiving XIB files; if you look closely, you'll see that `initWithFrame:` is not called for views you create in your XIB; they'll have `initWithCoder:` called instead.

Comment: Hi Ben, I get by just fine without this method when I'm using XIBs. For views I build programmatically I'm typically fine off with just loadView. For views I build with IB, I use viewDidLoad{}. So I'm trying to understand when it makes sense to use initWithCoder:

Answer (score 9):

User defaults is, basically, a property list. Property lists are similar to JSON and can only store specific types of data -- NSString, NSNumber, NSData, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary. If you try to store anything else in a user default, you'll get an exception. Property lists also can't handle arbitrary object graphs, only trees.

You could always take your custom state and convert it into a property-list compatible data structure, then store it in user defaults; but then you're basically implementing an object serialization mechanism, and you might as well use the more powerful one that's already provided by NSArchiver.

Answer (score 6):

`NSCoder` is the standard Cocoa method of implementing serialization. See Apple's [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I go with NSCoder whenever I have some sort of complicated data to store that I never have to edit by hand.  For example, my app [Converter](http://converterapp.com) stores currency exchange rates downloaded from the Internet in an NSCoder archive.  However, that's the only thing it keeps in such an archive: unit definitions, which are only ever altered by hand, are kept in a series of plist files in the application bundle, and things like the most recently selected units and values are kept in NSUserDefaults.